# "Connection Error" when trying to view FB image full size

Tags: images

Unable to view Facebook images full size. Get "connection error". I do not want to use the FB app. Until recently was no problem.
Samsung sm j120a

Comment: Is this really an Android question, or are you trying to report a problem in Facebook's website?

Comment: Good point Dan. I was wondering if this was something a future OS update might address but the comment from Lulu seems to point to the real culprit.